# How to perform a Left join clause on a pivot table?

Tags: laravel

How can i add `leftJoin` clause on the `pivot table`? For example in the code below, how can i add a `where` clause in `products_categories` to specify the `products` with `type='ELECTRONICS'` ?

```js
DB::table("products_categories")
->whereIn("category_id", array_values($ids))
->pluck("id")
->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can write it :

```
DB::table("products_categories")
->leftJoin('products', 'products.id', '=', 'products_categories.product_id')
->where('products.type', 'ELECTRONICS')
->whereIn("products_categories.category_id", array_values($ids))
->pluck("id")
->get();
```